STM32 RAM memory write HARD FAULT
I'm using STM32H755ZIT6 and I do have a global array in main.c file of CortexM7 :
uint8_t __attribute__ ((aligned (32))) buffer[4096];
and writing some data in it.
according the .map file it's address is 0x00000000240004a0 i.e RAM_D1.
Also I do have float2 type
typedef struct _float2
{
   float x;
   float y;

} float2;

Also I do have a pressure sensor and after reading it's pressure value
uint32_t PRESSURE I'm doing this
  float2* vec = (float2*)((u32)buffer);
  vec->x = (float)PRESSURE / 100;

and after vec->x assigning I'm getting HardFault .
But if I assign for example 97343.498(which can't fint in uint8_t type) then it works, like vec->x = 97343.498
I don't understand what's going on.
P.S Tried to allocate buffer in RAM_D3, RAM_D2 but the same result.
What is the difference between vec->x = (float)PRESSURE / 100; and vec->x = 97343.498 ?
I checked disassembly and it fails on the first instruction:
   vec->x = ((float)D/(float)100);
   ldr     r3, [r7, #8]         <-----  FAILS HERE
   vmov    s15, r3
   vcvt.f32.u32    s14, s15
   vldr    s13, [pc, #104] ; 0x80048ac <Ad_Solem+316>
   vdiv.f32        s15, s14, s13
   ldr     r3, [r7, #4]
   vstr    s15, [r3]

It fails when loading r3 register from (r7 + 8) offset.
BUT if I write this
  vec->x = 97343.498;

then assembly code looks like
  ldr     r3, [r7, #4]

and it does not fail.
BTW the value of the register r7 is 0x2407ffc8
and my uint8_t buffer[4096] is allocated at 0x24000484 address.

You are assigning a float type value into a memory area which is said to contain uint32_t values. Isn't that undefined behaviour or is your compiler supposed to do something useful correctly when you want undefined things?

@Justme if I set vec->x or vec->y like this vec->x = 9833.5f; then it works fine.
but with (float)PRESSURE/100 does not. As you can see 9833.5 cant fit inside uint8_t.

Have you debugged what happens and why? Single stepped through asm code?

@Justme I'll check

@Justme I uploaded disassembly code, please look at

You need to use the debugger. Looks like whatever was in r7 was wrong. You will see what’s there in the debugger. It’s not very helpful to show the last instruction in the sequence that caused the fault. What’s next doesn’t matter - the CPU never got to execute it. What’s before it matters a lot :)

@Justme please see updated original post.

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica please see updated original post
